# adding arrow key navigation

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

Can you help me add arrow key navigation, where when I click the right arrow, it shows the next question, and when I press the left arrow, it goes to the previous question?

here is the code:

```js
let currentQuestion = 1;

function answer(answer) {
  // set the value of the current question's input
  let input = document.getElementById(`q${currentQuestion}-input`);
  input.value = answer;

  // hide the current question
  let question = document.getElementById(`question-${currentQuestion}`);
  question.style.display = 'none';

  // show the next question or submit button
  currentQuestion++;
  if(currentQuestion > 4) {
    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    let nextQuestion = document.getElementById(`question-${currentQuestion}`);
    nextQuestion.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  </div>

  <div id="question-1">
    <h2>Question 1</h2>
    <p>What is your favorite color?</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">Red</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">Green</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">Blue</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">Yellow</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="q1" id="q1-input">
  </div>

  <div id="question-2" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Question 2</h2>
    <p>What is your favorite food?</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">Pizza</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">Burgers</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">Tacos</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">Sushi</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="q2" id="q2-input">
  </div>

  <div id="question-3" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Question 3</h2>
    <p>What is your birth day?</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">A</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">B</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">C</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">D</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="q3" id="q3-input">
  </div>
  <div id="question-4" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Question 4</h2>
    <p>What is the number of cars in the city?</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">A</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">B</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">C</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">D</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="q4" id="q4-input">
  </div>

  <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Every time I tried to add anything, the code would just work without the arrow thing. I tried `e.keycheck`. I don't know how to even start fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have added basic implementation. You can take this further and add your own logic.

```js
let currentQuestion = 1;

function answer(answer) {
  // set the value of the current question's input
  let input = document.getElementById(`q${currentQuestion}-input`);
  input.value = answer;

  // hide the current question
  let question = document.getElementById(`question-${currentQuestion}`);
  question.style.display = 'none';

  // show the next question or submit button
  currentQuestion++;
  if(currentQuestion > 4) {
    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    let nextQuestion = document.getElementById(`question-${currentQuestion}`);
    nextQuestion.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

// KEY HANDLER
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  // advance currentQuestion based on key pressed
  if (e.keyCode === 39) { // code 39 checks right arrow key
currentQuestion++;
  } else if (e.keyCode === 37) { // code 37 checks left arrow key. 
    currentQuestion--;
  }
  
  // Hide other questions
  document.querySelectorAll('.question').forEach(
    question => question.style.display = "none"
  );
  
  // Display current question
  document.getElementById(`question-${currentQuestion}`).style.display = 'block';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Your name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="question-1">
      <h2>Question 1</h2>
      <p>What is your favorite color?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">Red</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">Green</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">Blue</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">Yellow</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="q1" id="q1-input">
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="question-2" style="display:none;">
      <h2>Question 2</h2>
      <p>What is your favorite food?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">Pizza</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">Burgers</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">Tacos</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">Sushi</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="q2" id="q2-input">
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="question-3" style="display:none;">
      <h2>Question 3</h2>
      <p>What is your birth day?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">A</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">B</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">C</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">D</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="q3" id="q3-input">
    </div>
    
    <div class="question" id="question-4" style="display:none;">
      <h2>Question 4</h2>
      <p>What is the number of cars in the city?</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('a')">A</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('b')">B</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('c')">C</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="answer('d')">D</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="q4" id="q4-input">
    </div>

    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to share few tips:

1. You should modularise your code. Add functions to separate the concerns.
2. Functions should handle single responsibility only.
   Eg. Your answer function is setting answer.
   But it is doing other jobs as well like advancing current question, hiding current question, displaying next question.
3. Instead of changing style attributes (element.style.display), create classes and apply them conditionally.